# How to avoid stack overflow error

Tags: java, recurrence

I have a program which can be defined as something like this

```
reset() {
   //sets all variables to initial values
   //clears all arrays
   method1();
}

method1 (){
    //doSomeStuff;
    method2();
}

method2(){
    //doStuff
    method3();
}

method3(){
    //doStuff
    if (jobDone) reset(); //here the cycle closes
    else method2();
}
```

All these methods are quite calculations heavy.
Depending on the input data and the result the program may do just a couple of cycles and throw a 'stack overflow' error.

I have changed the VM flag -Xss (`-Xss8M`) but this doesn't really solve the problem.

Is there any way to make it working almost infinitely?

Comment: Well it's not clear from this pseudo-code what the point of all this is. You basically want to get rid of the recursion... but we have no idea how you should do that without knowing what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Increase it further: -Xss16m

Comment: As far as I can see, `reset` calls `method1` that class `method2` that class `method3` that can call `method2` or `reset` and going into an infinite cycle (thus giving your `StackOverflowError`).

Comment: I suspect you have a rather generous definition of the word "couple". Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: @BenHocking Nope, it can be literally 3-5 cycles.

Comment: @strah: then are the various `//doStuff` sections making a lot of function calls? On the off chance that your `-Xss8M` flag is making things worse, have you tried it *without* setting the flag to see how many cycles are required before crashing?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes, it is/should be infinite cycle (well, not exactly, but should do thousands cycles).

Comment: @BenHocking without the flag it can stop before completing the first cycle.

Comment: I would return from every method after `jobDone` is `true` until get to `reset` method again in order to avoid the SOE. Since this has to be eternal (per your comment), then wrap the `reset` method call in a `while(true){ ... }` segment.

Comment: @strah on what line is it returning a stack overflow, then? Is it possibly because of what you have in the `//doStuff` code and the recursion you're pointing to is actually a red herring? That would be my guess…

Comment: If it is indeed true that it only runs 3-5 cycles, there is likely a problem somewhere else. Either way, my best advice - try to construct a minimum test case reproducing the problem (more for yourself than for us). This could involve commenting out parts of the code to narrow down the problem, which will more than likely point to what's wrong.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Wrapping the content of `reset` in `while` loop worked like a charm (See the answer below). @Dukeling, thankfully there where no other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution previously mentioned by Luiggi Mendoza: [How to avoid stack overflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734657/how-to-avoid-stack-overflow-error?noredirect=1#comment22355674_15734657)**

When you call reset, it calls method1, it calls method2, it calls method3 and it calls either reset or method2 both causing infinite cycle in recursion.

You probably want:

```
if (jobDone) return; // here the cycle realy closes
```

instead of

```
if (jobDone) reset(); //here the do _not_ close
```

In case you realy want infinite cycling of your code this will not cause SO due to method calling of reset or methodi:

```
// assuming jobDone is actually a method, you might need this variable
boolean startReset = true;
while (true) {
        if (startReset) {
            //sets all variables to initial values
            //clears all arrays

            //doSomeStuff from method1;
        }
        //doStuff from method2

        //doStuff
        startReset = jobDone;
    }
}
```

Comment: @strah [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734657/how-to-avoid-stack-overflow-error?noredirect=1#comment22355674_15734657) was turned into an answer =\

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza that's why I thanked you in the thread above too. :-)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry, I just roughly looked over comments and did not noticed the cycle you mentioned. I meant nothing bad ;o)

Comment: @kyticka don't worry, this happened to me lot of times, glad to know I'm not the only one who though about this alternative and that worked.